# Why is my Google Maps API callback executing before the preceding inline script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, asp.net-core, callback

```
<script src="/js/site.js?v=EtZhOXlkRte5HDRXpfS7rDy3ua0sbCvtNJUaIlNsSXw"></script>
<script>
    var init;
    $(function () {
        var adpSummaryListenerId;
        init = _initializeDirections;
        initializeAdpSummaryListener();

        function _initializeDirections() {
            console.log("test"); //we don't get here, sometimes
            var origin = {
                isGoogle: $("#origin-isgoogle").val(),
                coordinate: new google.maps.LatLng(@origin.Latitude, @origin.Longitude),
                address: "@origin.StreetAddress",
                marker: "@origin.MarkerName"
            }, destination = {
                isGoogle: $("#destination-isgoogle").val(),
                coordinate: new google.maps.LatLng(@destination.Latitude, @destination.Longitude),
                address: "@destination.StreetAddress",
                marker: "@destination.MarkerName"
            }, start = {
                value: origin.isGoogle ? origin.address : origin.coordinate,
                pos: origin.coordinate,
                marker: origin.marker
            }, end = {
                value: destination.isGoogle ? destination.address : destination.coordinate,
                pos: destination.coordinate,
                marker: destination.marker
            };

            console.log("Initializing directions");
            initializeDirections(start, end); //in site.js
        }

        function initializeAdpSummaryListener() {
            adpSummaryListenerId = window.setInterval(addNavigateButton, 500);
        }

        function addNavigateButton() {
            console.log("checking for .adp-summary");
            if ($(".adp-summary").length) {
                $(".adp-summary").append($("#start-navigation").html());
                clearInterval(adpSummaryListenerId);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=@(Model.GoogleMapsApiKey)&callback=init"></script>
```

I can't figure out why, despite the maps script being referenced *after* the inline script, the Google Maps API callback `init` is sometimes not instantiated before Google attempts to call it.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Uncaught (in promise)
ld {message: "init is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error at new ld (https://maps.googleapis.com/.......&callback=init:141:124"}
```

I previously had the callback name as `initializeMap` as a reference declared in site.js (but still initialized here in the inline script), but moved it here for brevity and isolation, hoping I would be able to figure out the issue. But the same problem persists.

I [understand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) that `async` directs the api to be fetched in parallel to parsing and evaluated as soon as it is available, but it shouldn't be available before the inline script, right?

I also understand that `defer` indicates that the api won't be executed until after the document is parsed, so it still shouldn't be available yet.

I did see this about `defer`:

> This attribute allows the elimination of parser-blocking JavaScript where the browser would have to load and evaluate scripts before continuing to parse. async has a similar effect in this case.

But `defer` still shouldn't prevent the inline script from executing first because it only enables JavaScript *to not have to be parser-blocking* if the attribute is used on the inline `<script>` tag.

So I'm at a loss.

Comment: Can't say for sure, it's been forever since I dealt with the maps API. But it is likely because you aren't defining your `init` function until after the DOM is loaded (it is defined inside your `$(function () { ... });`; whereas the script that uses (although it is defined after the script) is executing before the document ready event is fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your above inline script is indeed running first, but the `$(function () {` is a jQuery construct which only runs the callback inside once the document is ready. It looks like the Google script is running first.

If you give Google's script the `defer` attribute, it will only run once the DOM is finished being built, and the `$(function () {` will be unnecessary. So, just move everything out of the `$(function () {` so that `init` will be on the top level, and callable by Google when Google's script loads:

```
<script>
function init() {
            var origin = {
                isGoogle: $("#origin-isgoogle").val(),
                coordinate: new google.maps.LatLng(@origin.Latitude, @origin.Longitude),
                address: "@origin.StreetAddress",
                marker: "@origin.MarkerName"
            }, destination = 
            // etc
```

Note that while you can use `async` or `defer`, you shouldn't use both. To wait until the DOM is loaded, use `defer` and not `async`.

There is *one* thing that your above inline script does other than assign to variables, which is call `initializeAdpSummaryListener`. You can put this inside `$(function () {` if you need to make sure the DOM is loaded before it runs:

```
$(initializeAdpSummaryListener);
```

Another option whose control flow might be easier to understand would be to put *everything* in a named function that Google calls when it loads (which, given the `defer` attribute, will occur only once the page loads).

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds. :)

Comment: Ah man. I knew that, but it didn't click for me because I used the shorthand for $(document).ready. Thanks for the answer. I'll mark it as correct, and I'll check in the morning.